# IntelliJ library in project libs folder still unable to be picked up in classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shared-libraries, classpath

I am trying to use the apache-poi-3 library, and while it works fine at compile time, running the library class/method calls returns a NoClassDefFoundError. I created a /libs folder under my main Project module's trunk. This trunk has /src and an /out/production as well.

My understanding of classpath for IntelliJ allows you to have the /libs folder as the root for libraries. Just dragging a folder of jars in there should work.

I am not sure how the process works. I have another library here that I just went into Project Structure-> Libraries -> new Library and even tried going to Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependancies -> add Jars/Dependencies with no luck for apache-poi-3.

[image: Apache-poi-3 failure to add library to classpath.png]

Comment: Use a dependency manager, such as maven (or gradle if you're a masochist) -- they exist to solve this problem and are pretty easy. Doing this through the IDE is painful, error prone, and hard.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting all jars into the /libs/ folder. No jars are children of any other folder other than /libs. Im pretty sure this is how it should have been deployed and zipped up as, but whatever.